# How do I open a pypy process from an ordinary python program?

Tags: python, subprocess, pypy

I run a simple piece of code using python which I would like to open another program in pypy (as this is much faster).

I would also like to be able to pass in a dictionary into the pypy program.

I can get the file to open using...

```
subprocess.Popen(['c:\pypy-2.0-beta1\pypy.exe', os.path.expanduser('Main.py')])
```

but I have no idea how to pass in a dictionary or how to open a specific function within the pypy program.

Comment: this would be the same as starting any other program using subprocess. You'll need some sort of IPC mechanism.

Comment: what is an IPC mechanism?

Comment: IPC is InterProcess Communication. It basically a complicated way of saying "some way for process to pass information". Files, sockets, and pipes are examples of IPC mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into execnet (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/execnet), it's a pretty cool library to do this kind of stuff.